# If, Else inside html using Django templates

Tags: python, html, django, if-statement

I have a Django project that consists of many html pages.

I want to add an if else condition inside my html tag to return "None" whenever the time stamp = 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and return the time when it's not. My code is shown below, I used a tag to get the time in date format.

`<td>{{ table.start_time|date:"Y-m-d G:i:s"}}</td>`

Comment: if you need to code something in HTML, you usually want to use java-script for that. investigate into that, read tutorials and so on.

Comment: I suppose the OP requires this done at server-side.

Comment: No way to do it inside the html tags?

Comment: Yes, just read the answers. Btw, welcome to SO. You should edit your title to be more descriptive since you are working with Django so, you want this to work with Django templating engine, not just with plain html.

Comment: How can you even get that time? What am I missing here? I know you're probably trying to do some sort of timer related field, but I tried, and I can't get that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used another tag:

`<td>{{ table.start_time|date:"Y-m-d G:i:s"|default:"None"}}</td>`

Thanks all!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `ifequal` template tag.

```
{% with table.start_time|date:"Y-m-d G:i:s" as start_time %}
    {% ifequal start_time "0000-00-00 00:00:00" %}None{% else %}{{start_time}}{% endifequal %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: `ifequal` was deprecated long time ago... https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/releases/1.2/#smart-if-tag

Comment: It is not deprecated https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal. You can also use the `if` tag with the != or other python operators. But `ifequal` and `ifnotequal` are still there.

Comment: Quoted directly from the link I attached before: `There’s really no reason to use {% ifequal %} or {% ifnotequal %} anymore, unless you’re the nostalgic type.` This points more to a deprecation than anything else...

Comment: Well, the day they will set it as a deprecated one I'll stop using but right now there isn't event a warning nor something similar in the current documentation. "An alternative to the ifequal tag is to use the if tag and the == operator." doesn't feel as they are going to deprecate it. May be I'm in the "nostalgic" category since I have some old projects using this tag and that's why it is natural for me to use it.

Comment: Then, you're free to use the nostalgic version :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
{% with table.start_time|date:"Y-m-d G:i:s" as time_stamp %}
    {% if time_stamp != "0000-00-00 00:00:00" %}
        <td>{{ time_stamp }}</td>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I have tried like this way, but not working.
`{% with table.start_time|date:"Y-m-d G:i:s" as time_stamp %}
       {% if time_stamp = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" %}
    <td> "None" </td>
    {% else %}
          <td>{{ time_stamp }}</td>
       {% endif %}
   {% endwith %}`

Comment: The equal operator is `==` not `=` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#operator

Comment: The code should be correct, what is the output of `{{ time_stamp }}` outside the `if`s?

Comment: Those fields which don't have any None times

Comment: This doesn't help, please paste the exact output of these values.

Answer (score 1):

There is no if-then control explanation in HTML, or whatever other programming capacities. HTML is a markup dialect. Writing computer programs isn't conceivable.

Css will permit you to pick between styles in light of classes and IDs.

You can do this sort of thing with JavaScript, yet you can keep it straightforward with CSS.